# Legally Playing DVDs post-April 2021

Tags: software-recommendation, dvd, legal, fluendo

https://fluendo.com/en/blog/post/oneplay-dvd-player-product-discontinuation/

If I'm reading this right, it seems that the primary legal DVD player that [Ubuntu recommends](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/video-dvd-restricted.html) was discontinued last April, before I had the opportunity to purchase a license. Considering this, I was wondering if you all have any suggestions as to what alternatives I could pursue that do not involve brute-force decryption software like libdvdcss does or whatever VLC uses.

If it helps, I am under United States jurisdiction. I am also willing to purchase commercial products for a reasonable price.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/video-dvd-restricted.html.

Beyond that, pretty much every site that I go to will recommend Fluendo DVD player (howtogeek, etc.).

Comment: At the bottom of that page, please click "file a bug" to update the documentation.

Comment: File a bugreport against https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/video-dvd-restricted.html  and it will get removed. Mind that this also means when your license runs out playing encrypted dvd's might be illegal (it will depend on each country). Fluendo does NOT list an alternative. No idea if there are newer software from them.

Comment: Its not that I'm concerned of my license running out. I don't have one. I was going to get one, but then I found out about the discontinuation.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1928017

The bug report is in.

Comment: @MediaPhysics: It would be good if you (or anybody who reads this) could check whether the "Use alternative decryption software" section at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/video-dvd-restricted.html) is still useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of those programs rely on brute-force hacking to break the CSS encryption, which is illegal in the United States. I'm looking for a program that lets me play DVDs without breaking these laws.

Comment: @MediaPhysics: I see. If you find anything, I'd appreciate a hint.

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson: So far, there may be a bit of promise in the "analog loophole" if you happen to have an old DVD player or 7th-gen console, but the law is rather obscure about this, so I'm not entirely sure. Of course, if you have one of these, it sort of defeats the point of using your computer's DVD player unless you are wanting to back one up.